# Javascript create recursive unordered list from ordered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have the following HTML

```
<ol data-level="0">
    <li class="active">This is the data1</li>
</ol>
<ol data-level="1">
    <li class="active">This is the data2</li>
</ol>
<ol data-level="2">
    <li class="active">This is the data3</li>
</ol>
<ol data-level="3">
    <li class="active">This is the data4</li>
</ol>
<ol data-level="2">
    <li class="active">This is the data5</li>
</ol>
<ol data-level="2">
    <li class="active">This is the data6</li>
</ol>
<ol data-level="0">
    <li class="active">This is the data7</li>
</ol>
```

Below you can see the outcome of the above HTML (I stripped out some html tags for better readability!). [image: Indents]

I have to create a valid unordered list from this outcome. I've searched around stackoverflow and I came across multiple solutions. E.g. making use of a recursive function. The problem with this is that I don't know how to pass in the objects that belong to the 'root' object (see: [How can I recursively create a UL/LI's from JSON data - multiple layers deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362446/how-can-i-recursively-create-a-ul-lis-from-json-data-multiple-layers-deep)).

At the moment I'm stuck with this code:

```
var $root = $items.first();
var rootLvl = $root.data('level');
var prevLvl = rootLvl;

function recursiveCheck($next) {
    prevLvl = $next.data('level');
    var nextItem = $next.next();

    if (nextItem.data('level') > prevLvl) {
        console.log('check');
        recursiveCheck(nextItem);
    } else {
        console.log('break');
    }
}

recursiveCheck($root);
```

At the 'break' I don't know how to go back to the previous root element.. Can someone pull me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: My desired outcome is like this:

```
    <ul>
        <li>Data 1
            <ul>
                <li> Data 2
                    <ul>
                        <li> Data 3
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    Data 4
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>Data 5
                        </li>
                        <li>Data 6
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Data 7
        </li>
    </ul>
```

More information

```
- level 1 
- - level 2 // this belongs to the first level 1
- - - level 3 // this belongs to level 2
- - - level 3 // this belongs to level 2
- - - level 3 // this belongs to level 2
- - level 2 // this belongs to the first level 1
- level 1 
- - level 2 // this belongs to the second level 1
```

in this example the first level 1 has two level 2 subitems, but one of them also has three level 3 subitems. So I have to find out how to get the next  items with a higher level. I'm able to produce above string with '- - -'. I just can't convert this to an unordered list.

Solved, final code:

```
edu.saveSummary = function() {
    var dataLevel = 'edu-draggable-level';
    var node = $('[data-edu-draggable]').first();

    function parseUL() {
        var level = node.data(dataLevel);
        var ul = document.createElement("ul");

        while (node && node.data(dataLevel) === level) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.textContent = node.text();
            ul.appendChild(li);
            node = node.next();
            if (node && +node.data(dataLevel) > level) {
                li.appendChild(parseUL());
            }
        }

        return ul;
    }

    return parseUL();
};
```

Comment: What is the actual output you want to achieve? "I have to create a valid unordered list from this outcome" is kinda ambiguous.

Comment: Added, sorry you are right :-)

Comment: Maybe I didn't get the point, but can you just show different indentations, e.g. give padding:30px for level 3...

Comment: For remembering elements in the tree-like structure while you're "traversing" them, you use stack structure. That might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines should work:

```
var node = first_ol_node;

function parseUL() {
    var level = +node.children().first().data('level');
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    while (node && +node.children().first().data('level') === level) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = node.text();
        ul.appendChild(li);
        node = node.next();
        if (node && +node.children().first().data(level) > level) {
            li.appendChild(parseUL());
        }
    }
    return ul;
}

var ul = parseUL();
```

One problem is that you need both to return the parsed `ul` node from the function and you also need to advance the parsing pointer over the source items (and in Javascript there's no way to pass a variable by reference, you can only pass by value).

In this solution I'm using an external variable instead of a parameter to keep the current pointer in the source items (advanced in `node = node.next()`) and the return value is the parsed UL.

Comment: If I use your code my browser crashes, I think it's in an endless loop. 

I changed a bit to your code e.g. +node.children().first().data, I changed this to +node.data(), the data is in the OL tag not in the LI tag? Or do I miss something here? 

Thanks for your answer though, I'll keep trying and trying..

Comment: I solved my problem, I removed the '+' sign and now it works.
@6502 can you tell me what's the '+' sign used for?

Comment: @DieterGoetelen: Sorry... I didn't test the code at all, I added the `+` to force a numeric conversion and avoid surprises with comparison. Just double check if it works with level `"2"` not being considered bigger than level `"12"`.